# Clean install of Win10 on homebuilt computer

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, clean-install

I hope my post is in the right SE section, please let me know if my post shouldn't rely on SU.

## Abstract

I recently bought my computer (homebuilt), and I now try to install Win10 on it. I have a single problem that I don't manage to get through: when booting on the USB device, the install freezes after few seconds.

## Long Story

After having a laptop, I want a desk computer. With the advices of a friend, I bought components separately (with special offer). You can find all components [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/dG7gwh). I then downloaded the Win10 Media Creation Tool [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10). I tried both:
- Create installation media (USB flash drive)
- Create installation media (ISO) and use Rufus to put it on an USB device

In both case, the same things happen:
1. Logo shortly appears
2. Boot on USB device
3. Windows loading dots appears

And now different possibilities:
- Screen freezes while dots are turning
- ***Installation starts*** screen appears for an eternity
- ***Installation starts*** screen appears then language selection screen appears and freezes
- I manage to hit ***Next*** during language selection, it asks my product key and freezes

I have tried to stay on the language selection screen when it worked, and after a few seconds the screen freezes as well. I have tried to wait for a whole night, still frozen. I have tried two different USB devices (16Go and 8Go), same results. When in BIOS menu, screen never froze.

I noticed this morning that, when I start my computer, the *EZ Debug LED* are lighting on for a short time, in this order:

```
[BOOT] [VGA] [DRAM] [CPU]   - off    • on

---• (0.2s)   --•- (0.2s)   ---- (4s)
-•-- (4s)     •--- (0.1s)   ---- (forever)
```

Edit 1: Ubuntu installation works perfectly, Win7 installation fails as well
**Edit 2: Win10 installation works on another computer**
I do NOT have a disc drive, so USB is my only choice.

### Things I already tried

- power off and disconnect for half an hour
- factory reset the motherboard
- not to use the 3.0 USB slots
- disconnect a ram memory
- disconnect the other ram memory
- disconnect mouse and keyboard
- disconnect SSD
- disconnect HDD
- probably some other things I forgot

**Does anyone know what is the problem, and how I could fix it?**

Comment: Download the ISO again and create the installation media again.  If that doesn’t work you have a hardware problem

Comment: I did it, still does not work. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you reviewed the motherboard's manual to decipher the LED diagnostic lights?

Comment: Yes, and please don't laugh. _Indicates **CPU/DRAM/GPU/Booting Device** is not detected or fail._ That's all. Anyway, I found on a forum that it is normal that the two first lights quickly light on.

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda - If the motherboard does not POST that is typically an indication of a hardware problem with the motherboard and/or processor

Comment: Added Edit: Ubuntu installation works perfectly.

Comment: Try booting the windows usb on another machine.  Narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: It works on another computer.

Comment: Try upgrading or downgrading the Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) of your motherboard. However this process is risky as power failure while upgrading firmware (and you have no UPS or so) could brick your motherboard. Try older Windows 10 e.g. v1809.

Comment: In my experience, I have seen bad memory cause Windows to fail instll, yet allow Linux.  I would run memtestx86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [@Keltari](https://superuser.com/users/94133/keltari)'s comment, I tried to use [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/). However, my BIOS didn't recognize the key, so I searched for a solution, and the only one was to **flash my motherboard**, which I did.

As this solution has already been adviced to solve my problem, I tried to install Win10 before using memtest86. I didn't want to do it before, because all advices were followed by ***At your own risk***, and I was scared.

**Flashing my BIOS actually solved my problem.** It was really easy (using M-Flash), and fast (which limits the probabilities of powering off).